# Django - get param from request.get and add it with another number

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have following code. I want to get values from from request and add it to another float number. I tried this code but gives me error :*unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType'*

```
class RatingsUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):

    serializer_class = serializers.RatingsSerializer

    queryset = models.Ratings.objects.all()


    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        #average =
        instance.total_number = instance.total_number + 1
        instance.sum_of_all_ratings =instance.sum_of_all_ratings + request.data.get("rating_give_by_user")

        instance.save()
```

Look at the line where i am getting value *'request.data.get("rating_give_by_user")_give_by_user'*. This value us NoneType but i want to add it to another float number. What is the solution and best practice. Thanks.

Comment: If it's giving None, that means the parameter is not being supplied. Why do you want to add None to an existing number anyway? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am receiving a rating value from request.data.get() so i want to add that rating given by user to some number existing in db(models)

Comment: Let me ask this with another perspective. How do i get a value from params of request.data.get('rating_give_by_user') and add that value to existing number in DB.

Comment: You get it like that, but this error is telling you that that value *is not being supplied* in the data.

Answer (score 0):

`request.data.get("rating_give_by_user")` is returning `None` and you are attempting to add this to a number. What do you expect this method call to return? An (int, str...)? Ensure that the GET parameter is properly being passed because right now django isn't seeing it.

Comment: I know the code is wrong but I am receiving a rating value from request.data.get() so i want to add that rating value given by user to some number existing in db(models)

Answer (score 0):

You must check get param exists, try this:

```
rating = request.GET.get("rating_give_by_user", None)
if rating:
    instance.sum_of_all_ratings = instance.sum_of_all_ratings + rating
```